# Export the contents of a dictionary to a m x n matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I have a dictionary where the number of objects can change. The type of each object will always be a 3 element ND array. For example:

```
exampleDict = {u'A': array([ 1, 2, 3]), u'B': array([ 2, 3, 4]), u'C': array([ 3, 4, 5]), u'D': array([ 4, 5, 6])}
```

Using a for loop, I would like to be able to create a matrix that looks like this:

```
exampleMatrix = array([[ 1, 2, 3], [ 2, 3, 4], [ 3, 4, 5], [ 4, 5, 6]])
```

I'm able to create a 0 matrix of the correct dimensions using:

```
exampleMatrix = np.zeros((len(exampleDict), 3))
```

But, I don't know how to fill that matrix appropriately. I was trying to use a for loop. I'm open to other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered in some versions of Python, do you want to use the key to sort?

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part here is that dictionaries are not guaranteed to be sorted in some versions of Python (definitely will not be sorted if you're using Python 2.7), so there has to be a way to determine the order of values for the final array.

Since it looks like you want to create an array in the alphabetical order of your keys, you can use a list comprehension and `sorted`:

```
np.array([v for _, v in sorted(exampleDict.items())])

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not necessarily looking for it to be "sorted", but rather, I want to keep the ordering consistent, so this works perfectly. 

For my own understanding, what does "v for _," do? I'm unfamiliar with that term?

Comment: When you look through `exampleDict.items()`, you're looping through a list of tuples.  Since we don't care about the `key` after we have our sorted list, you can use `_` as  "throwaway variable" to only unpack the value into the variable `v`

Comment: `np.stack(xampleDict.values())` may be enough

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the keys for future reference (comparing with other variables) and still treat it like a numpy array, then you can use Pandas' dataframe:

`my_array=pandas.DataFrame(exampleDict)`

Then you can do numpy operations on it, sometime you might have to use `my_array.values`.
Since you have keys, pandas might do a lot of the work in the rest of your code and save some headache. I'll recommend to take a look at it.

If you want to keep it simple, there's an easier way rather than the list comprehension of the other answer. Although I'm not sure if you'll be facing big arrays to make any difference, but the speed test with solutions are:

`np.array([v for _, v in (exampleDict.items())])`: 3.63u

`np.array([v for v in exampleDict.values()])`: 3.53u

`np.array(list(exampleDict.values()))`: 3.40u

It goes without saying that the pandas solution will take much longer than the other methods, it just keeps more information and "maybe" brings the speed up to your code somewhere else.